# Persist or reapply DataGrid.CellStyle after ICollectionView.Refresh()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I'm using a `ICollectionView` as `ItemsSource` for a `DataGrid`. Using a `Style`, I'm highlighting the cells of my `DataGrid` that contain a specific `SearchString`. Simultaneously I'd like to filter the `DataGrid` to display those lines that contain at least one cell that matches my search.

For the `ICollectionView.Filter` to effect the displayed data in my `DataGrid`, I need to call `ICollectionView.Refresh()`, which apparently clears the style of the cells, because the whole data is reloaded and displayed fresh.

What would be a way to preserve (or re-apply) the style of the cells after a `ICollectionView.Refresh()`?

Here is the code I'm using to style the cells:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContainsStringToBooleanConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.SearchString" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Here is how I'm filtering the `ICollectionView`:

```
ItemView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItemChildren);
ItemView.Filter = ItemViewFilter;
```

...

```
private bool ItemViewFilter(object o)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchString)) return true;

    var item = (o as Item);
    if (item == null) return true;

    bool result = (item.ItemText.ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToLower()));

    return result;
}
```

`Refresh()` is called every time `SearchString` is updated:

```
public string SearchString
{
    get
    {
        return mySearchString;
    }
    set
    {            
        mySearchString = value;
        ItemView.Refresh();
        OnPropertyChanged("SearchString");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
After mm8's comment I took a look at my `IMultiValueConverter`. It seems when the converter is called after a `Refresh`, none of the cells contain any text. Here is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values.Length != 2) return false;
    if (values[0] == null || values[1] == null) return false;

    string text = "";
    if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
    {
        // The TextBlock never contains any Text after a Refresh
        text = ((TextBlock)values[0]).Text; 
    }

    string search = values[1] as string;

    if (text == null || search == null) return false;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search)) return false;

    return text.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower());
    }
```

Comment: Does the Convert method of your converter gets hit after you call Refresh()?

Comment: Yes, `IMultiValueConverter.Convert()` is called after the `Refresh()`

Comment: But it doesn't return true? Then it means that there is something wrong with your convert logic. The background of the cell will be set only when the Convert method returns true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. It seems the cells never contain any text when the converter is called after the refresh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from my "filter & style" approach for highlighting cells and showing only the rows containing such highlighted cells to an style-only approach.

I added an additional `DataGrid.RowStyle` to hide the rows not containing my search string:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContainsStringToBooleanConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.SearchString" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This works pretty well and I feel like it might even be a little faster than the filter approach.